# How do i manage RAM usage by python?

Tags: python

I tried creating a script which would scrape the latest uploaded files on a public picture sharing website and use imageai to recognize what is in the picture,then move it to a folder called the best guess by imageai.
The script works but it's really slow and after like a minute it consumes 5GB of RAM which makes my PC unstable.

I am new to Python and programming this is my second project so far so i only tried a few things written in stackoverflow posts.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib3
import urllib
from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
import shutil, os
execution_path = os.getcwd()
from PIL import Image



proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager('proxy')

def make_soup(url):
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("GET", url)
return BeautifulSoup(r.data,'lxml')


ip = 'proxy'
proxies = {
  'http': ip,
  'https': ip,
}
default="space"
filetype = []
i = 1
soup = make_soup("link")

for img in soup.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('_tn.jpg')}):
os.chdir(default)
temp = img.get('src').replace("_tn","")
print(temp)
nametemp = img.get('alt').replace("png","jpg")
print(nametemp)
if str(nametemp) == 'None':
    filename = str(i)
    i = i+1
else:
    filename = nametemp



imagefile = open(filename , "wb")
imagefile.write(requests.get(temp).content)
imagefile.close()
print( filename + " mentve")
if ".png" in filename:
    try:
        im = Image.open(filename +".png")
        filetype = "png"
        print("this is a png")
        im.close()
    except IOError:
        print("png error")
if ".jpg" in filename:

    try:
        im=Image.open(filename)
        print("this is a jpg")
        filetype= "jpg"
        im.close()
        prediction = ImagePrediction()
        prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
        prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5"))
        prediction.loadModel()


        predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(execution_path, filename ), result_count=1 )
        for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
            print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
            dir = str(predictions[0])
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)
            os.chdir(dir)
            print(dir)
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            os.chdir(default)
            shutil.move(filename , dir)
        else:
            print("file already exists")
    except IOError:
            print("jpg error")
if ".jpeg" in filename:

    try:
        im=Image.open(filename)
        print("this is a jpeg")
        filetype= "jpeg"
        im.close()
    except IOError:
            print("jpeg error")                
print(filetype)
```

As i am seeking advice on what could be wrong with my code i provided it fully above. Sorry if it breaks any rules i think it's the logical step here.
I would love some advice on reading material or some kind of idea on what should i research to better understand how Python handles RAM usage.

Anything is appreciated, but keep in mind this is my second project so far.

Thank you.